# Ffmpeg returning error code 1 in AWS Lamda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I'm running a lambda function which takes an `mp4` video, and adds a watermark of a `png` image over the top of it in the bottom right hand corner (with a `10px` margin). It then outputs that image to a temporary location. It keeps failing with `Error code 1`, but that isn't very helpful. I'm using a binary version of `ffmpeg` that is specified in the main directory of the code. I know that `ffmpeg` is set up correctly due to using it in another lambda function in this way, which works. But adding an overlay fails. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
function addWatermark(next) {
    var ffmpeg = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", [
      "-i", target, // url to stream from
      "-i", watermarkPath,
      "-filter_complex" ,"overlay=x=W-w-10:y=H-h-10:format=rgb,format=yuv420p",
      "-c:a", "copy",
      "pipe:1"
    ]);
    ffmpeg.on("error", function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
    ffmpeg.on("close", function(code) {
      if (code != 0 ) {
        console.log("child process exited with code " + code); // Always exits here.
      } else {
        console.log("Processing finished !");
      }
      tmpFile.end(); 
      next(code);
    });
    tmpFile.on("error", function(err) {
      console.log("stream err: ", err);
    });
    ffmpeg.on("end", function() {
      tmpFile.end();  
    })
    ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(tmpFile)
    .on("error", function(err){
      console.log("error while writing: ",err);
    });
}
```

Can anyone spot what may be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've managed to print out some more logs, I'm getting the error:

```
[NULL @ 0x42923e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell ffmpeg what format you want the output in using the `-f format` option. Run `ffmpeg -formats` to get the list of supported formats.

From the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options):

> -f fmt (input/output)
>   Force input or output file format. The format is normally auto detected for input files and guessed from the file extension for output files, so this option is not needed in most cases.

For example, if you want the output as MPEG-4, then your call to ffmpeg should look like this:

```
   var ffmpeg = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", [
     "-i", target, // url to stream from
     "-i", watermarkPath,
     "-filter_complex" ,"overlay=x=W-w-10:y=H-h-10:format=rgb,format=yuv420p",
     "-c:a", "copy",
     "-f", "m4v",
     "pipe:1"
   ]);
```