# ffmpeg failed with code 1 firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add a logo overlay to a video in firebase-cloud-functions using ffmpeg. I have sucessfully run this command on my local machine.  I can't seem to access more indepth logging that just `failed with code 1`, and unsure what might be causing this issue ( the source files referenced exist in their location ).

```js
await spawn('ffmpeg', ['-i', filePath, '-i', logofilepath, '-filter_complex', '"overlay=20:20"', targetFilePath]);

console.log('Video with logo @', targetFilePath)
```

Error:

> ChildProcessError: `ffmpeg -i /tmp/input.mp4 -i /tmp/logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=20:20" /tmp/output.mp4` failed with code 1

Comment: I found this [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797534) with a problem very similar to yours (only difference is that it is in AWS), and the solution is that you have to force to `ffmpeg` the exit format by adding the `-f` parameter to your `ffmpeg` call, in that case you would have the following paramaters: `['-i', filePath, '-i', logofilepath, '-filter_complex', '"overlay=20:20"', "-f", "mp4", targetFilePath]`. Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: @RafaelLemos still the same issue unfortunately

Comment: Is this the only error that appears in the logs? Could you share more of your function so that I could try and replicate the issue?